# The code below is not entering the if($user) statment in register.php file

Tags: php, json, database

I have tried out some code for user registration..every gose fine code works and user data is stored into data base but in register.php file the execution is not entering if($user) statement as the $response of user details..!plz help me out and correct me if am wrong some were...
    hear gose the 
           /*DB_Functions.php*/

```
<?php
    class DB_Functions {
        private $db;

        // constructor
        function __construct() {
            try {
                $hostname = "localhost";
                $dbname = "miisky";
                $dbuser = "root";
                $dbpass = "";
                $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        /**
          * Storing new user
          * returns user details
          */
        public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile) {  
            try {
                $hash = md5($password);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password, mobile, created_at) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$hash', '$mobile', NOW())";
                $dbh = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $dbh->execute();
                $result = $this->db->query($sql);

                if ($result) {
                    // get user details
                    $id = $this->db->lastInsertId(); //last inserted id
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_name WHERE email = '$email'";
                    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                    $no_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
                    // returns confirmation message if completed
                    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
                        return "existsandcompleted";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = 'Error accessing database: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

and here gose the /*register.php*/ file were the main problem is...!!

```
<?php
require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);
if (isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['mobile'])) {
    // receiving the post params
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

    // create a new user
    $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["id"];
        $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
        $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (fname, lname, email, password or mobile) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: You're just swallowing all Exceptions, so you have absolutely no way of actually telling of something is going wrong. This is generally a bad idea for the obvious reason that it's very very hard to debug!

Comment: okay..!! thanks for feedback..how can i improve over this..?

Comment: @krishna you should return `true` or `false` from `storeUser()` method

Comment: can u plz provide code snippet..!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

> user data is stored into data base but in register.php file the execution is not entering if($user) statement as the $response of user details

**Solution:**

I'm pretty sure the problem is because of the following line,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_name WHERE email = '$email'";
                        ^
```

I think it should be,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
                        ^
```

Moreover, your `storeUser()` method should be like this:

```
// your code

public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile) {  
    try {
        $hash = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, email, password, mobile, created_at) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$hash', '$mobile', NOW())";
        $dbh = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        if($dbh->execute()){
            // get user details
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1";
            $dbh = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $result = $dbh->execute();
            $rows = $dbh->fetch();
            $n = count($rows);
            if($n){
                return $rows;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error accessing database: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return false;
}

// your code
```

Comment: sir..!!sadly its showing me the same message i.e {"error":true,"error_msg":"Unknown error occurred in registration!"} its not at all entering $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile);
    if ($user) { in register.php code is directly jumping on to :else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);

Comment: got it sir...some mistake in true and false statements got shuffled

Comment: but sir its {"error":false,"uid":null,"user":{"fname":null,"lname":null,"email":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}}all null not showing actual data

Comment: @krishna I've updated the entire `storeUser()` method. Please test your application with the updated code.

Comment: wow..working lik charm sir...thanks for helping me out of this u saved ma day..!!:)